# Can't call the second activity in android

Tags: android, json, android-intent

In My first Activity, I have three `Spinner` and three `EditText` and I need to pass selected data to second activity and parse them to json object.I got problem in calling the second activity. Thanks

**First Activity**

```
public class AndroidspinnerActivity extends Activity
{
    private ArrayList<Country> countryList;
    EditText subjname, slperiod, sldate;
    Spinner deptsp, degreesp, yearsp;
    DatePicker datepicker;

    void showToast(CharSequence msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        String url = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/SpinnerJson/CountryServlet";
        grabURL(url);
    }

    public void grabURL(String url)
    {
        Log.v("Android Spinner JSON Data Activity", url);
        new GrabURL().execute(url);
    }

    private void displayCountries(String response)
    {
        JSONObject responseObj = null;
        try
        {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            responseObj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray countryListObj = responseObj.getJSONArray("countryList");

            countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            String[] dept_array = new String[countryListObj.length()];
            String[] degree_array = new String[countryListObj.length()];
            String[] year_array = new String[countryListObj.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < countryListObj.length(); i++)
            {
                // add to country names array
                dept_array[i] = countryListObj.getJSONObject(i).getString("deptname");
                degree_array[i] = countryListObj.getJSONObject(i).getString("degree");
                year_array[i] = countryListObj.getJSONObject(i).getString("year");
                // get the country information JSON object
                String countryInfo = countryListObj.getJSONObject(i).toString();
                // create java object from the JSON object
                Country country = gson.fromJson(countryInfo, Country.class);
                // add to country array list
                countryList.add(country);

            }
            deptsp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dept_array);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            deptsp.setAdapter(adapter);
            deptsp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {}
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {}
            });

            degreesp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner02);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, degree_array);
            adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            degreesp.setAdapter(adapter1);
            degreesp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {}
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {}
            });

            yearsp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner03);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, year_array);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            yearsp.setAdapter(adapter2);
            yearsp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                {}
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {}

            });

            Button contbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_continue);
            contbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {

//                  String sldeptdp = deptsp.getSelectedItem().toString();
//                  String sldegreedp = degreesp.getSelectedItem().toString();
//                  String slyeardp = yearsp.getSelectedItem().toString();
//                  String subjnamee = subjname.getText().toString();
//                  String sldatee = sldate.getText().toString();
//                  String slperiodd = slperiod.getText().toString();
//                  JSONObject jsonobject;
//                  jsonobject = new JSONObject();
//                  try
//                  {
//                      jsonobject.put(sldeptdp, "");
//                      jsonobject.put(sldegreedp, "");
//                      jsonobject.put(slyeardp, "");
//                      jsonobject.put(subjnamee, "");
//                      jsonobject.put(sldatee, "");
//                      jsonobject.put(slperiodd, "");
//                      showToast((jsonobject.toString(2)));
//                  }
//                  catch (JSONException ex)
//                  {}

                    onclickgo();
                }
            });
            // subj name
            subjname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_sub);
            subjname.getText().toString();
            // date
            sldate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_date);
            sldate.getText().toString();
            slperiod = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_period);
            slperiod.getText().toString();

        }
        catch (JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String sldeptdp = deptsp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String sldegreedp = degreesp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String slyeardp = yearsp.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String subjnamee = subjname.getText().toString();
        String sldatee = sldate.getText().toString();
        String slperiodd = slperiod.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Parshingdata.class);
        intent.putExtra("sldept", sldeptdp);
        intent.putExtra("sldegree", sldegreedp);
        intent.putExtra("slyear", slyeardp);
        intent.putExtra("slsubjname", subjnamee);
        intent.putExtra("sldate", sldatee);
        intent.putExtra("slperiod", slperiodd);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    protected void onclickgo()
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Parshingdata.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
        private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
        private final HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = httpclient.getParams();
        HttpResponse response;
        private String content = null;
        private boolean error = false;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidspinnerActivity.this);

        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            dialog.setMessage("Getting your data... Please wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            String URL = null;
            try
            {
                URL = urls[0];
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);
                ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, WAIT_TIMEOUT);

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fakeInput", "not in USE for this demo"));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
                {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    content = out.toString();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Closes the connection.
                    Log.w("HTTP1:", statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            }
            catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {
                Log.w("HTTP2:", e);
                content = e.getMessage();
                error = true;
                cancel(true);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Log.w("HTTP3:", e);
                content = e.getMessage();
                error = true;
                cancel(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.w("HTTP4:", e);
                content = e.getMessage();
                error = true;
                cancel(true);
            }

            return content;
        }

        protected void onCancelled()
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(AndroidspinnerActivity.this, "Error connecting to Server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
            toast.show();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String content)
        {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast toast;
            if (error)
            {
                toast = Toast.makeText(AndroidspinnerActivity.this, content, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP, 25, 400);
                toast.show();
            }
            else
            {
                displayCountries(content);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

**Second Activity**

```
public class Parshingdata extends Activity
{

    void showToast(CharSequence msg)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.takeattnd);

        String sldept = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldept");
        String sldegree = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldegree");
        String slyear = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slyear");
        String slsubjname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slsubjname");
        String slperiod = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slperiod");
        String sldate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldate");
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            jsonobject.put(sldept, "");
            jsonobject.put(sldegree, "");
            jsonobject.put(slyear, "");
            jsonobject.put(slsubjname, "");
            jsonobject.put(sldate, "");
            jsonobject.put(slperiod, "");
            showToast((jsonobject.toString(2)));
        }
        catch (JSONException ex)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

LOG *show forced to close in emulator*

```
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ela.spinner/com.ela.spinner.Parshingdata}: java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at com.ela.spinner.Parshingdata.onCreate(Parshingdata.java:24) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920) 
05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): ... 11 more 05-16 19:19:35.984: D/dalvikvm(1015): GC_CONCURRENT freed 301K, 5% free 9491K/9927K, paused 12ms+94ms
```

Comment: Maybe would be useful if you could post the Logcat.

Comment: whats the problem? explain that

Comment: What do you mean with, problem calling the activity??, some error, a force close, a classNotFoundException??, be more explicit please

Comment: What error do you get? where? please post stack trace from logcat.

Comment: posted logs..got forced to close appliation.

Comment: Did you added the Activity in the manifest?

Comment: Have you solved this problem??

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting the extas with the intent. So when you are calling

```
String sldept = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldept");
```

Its not returning anything to put into you json object. So then you can't make a toast.

Comment: if that would be the case, it would end up in a `JSONException("Names must be non-null")`, which is caught without any log entry, but the application would run further with an empty `JSONObject`.

Answer (score 0):

Check these values, you are not getting one value from intent.

```
   String sldept = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldept");
   String sldegree = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldegree");
   String slyear = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slyear");
   String slsubjname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slsubjname");
   String slperiod = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slperiod");
   String  sldate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldate");
```

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 05-16 19:19:35.354: E/AndroidRuntime(1015): at >**com.ela.spinner.Parshingdata.onCreate(Parshingdata.java:24)**

This is where error occurs, so it means that the value of that variable is null, and that is sldate, i think which you getting from the intent.putExtra(). So check in actvity from where you calling this activity. Maybe you putting something wrong in intent.putExtra() regarading this varibale  "sldate" or "slperiod".

Answer (score 0):

`@Chintan Raghwani` was on the right track, considering that the problem really roots in the `onclickgo()` method of the `AndroidspinnerActivity` class.

If you call that method, no extras will be set for the intent, and thus when you call the `getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldept");` it throws a `NPE`.

Actually the `getIntent().getExtras()` is null (you have no extras set whatsoever!), and you still try to get a string from it.

To bypass this problem,

- either pass the extras to the intent of the `Parshingdata` class starting from `onclickgo`:

This way the `onclickgo()` method should be:

```
protected void onclickgo()
{
    String sldeptdp = deptsp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String sldegreedp = degreesp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String slyeardp = yearsp.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String subjnamee = subjname.getText().toString();
    String sldatee = sldate.getText().toString();
    String slperiodd = slperiod.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Parshingdata.class);
    intent.putExtra("sldept", sldeptdp);
    intent.putExtra("sldegree", sldegreedp);
    intent.putExtra("slyear", slyeardp);
    intent.putExtra("slsubjname", subjnamee);
    intent.putExtra("sldate", sldatee);
    intent.putExtra("slperiod", slperiodd);
    startActivity(intent);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

- or check the intent from within `Parshingdata`'s `onCreate` method for extras, and only perform the actions if the extras are available.

The `onCreate` method would look like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.takeattnd);

    if (getIntent().hasExtra("sldept"))
    {
        String sldept = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldept");
        String sldegree = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldegree");
        String slyear = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slyear");
        String slsubjname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slsubjname");
        String slperiod = getIntent().getExtras().getString("slperiod");
        String sldate = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sldate");
        JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject();
        try
        {
            jsonobject.put(sldept, "");
            jsonobject.put(sldegree, "");
            jsonobject.put(slyear, "");
            jsonobject.put(slsubjname, "");
            jsonobject.put(sldate, "");
            jsonobject.put(slperiod, "");
            showToast((jsonobject.toString(2)));
        }
        catch (JSONException ex)
        {
            Log.e("Error", "Error occured while populating the jsonobject", ex);
        }
    }
}
```

For the best, you should implement both.

Comment: when i start the activity the first activity displays the screen but it automatically go's to second activities screen and display the json data of default value from spinners.when select the details and click thr button application forced to close.

Comment: that's what I was describing above: Your `onclickgo` method does not pass any extras to the intent, just starts the new activity, so in `Parshingdata` you get a `NullPointerException` when trying to retrieve the extra values. Now I added a sample of how the `onclickgo` method should look like. Please see my update and find the implementation of that method.

Comment: ya now its working now.thank you so much for spending time and helping me.

Comment: you're welcome, glad to hear you managed to fix it. You should also consider accepting an answer, closing this question by it, this way others may learn from it too. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try following code with little change

```
protected void onclickgo() {
    Intent i = new Intent(AndroidspinnerActivity.this, Parshingdata.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

In the click event the context doesn't remain of your Activity, so you have to specify YourActivityName.this at time of Intent.

Comment: Error is about NullPointerException

Comment: I think you have not initialized spinner (or any other instance)

Comment: new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?               parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
                            {
                            String sldeptdp = deptsp.getSelectedItem().toString();}

Comment: I've told you dat you have not initialized any object.

Comment: TextView tv;
   tv.setText("String");

Comment: you have to do somethin like dis

Comment: TextView tv1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());

Comment: i mean i need initialize every textview am using.

Comment: I am not talking about ONLY textview,  i m tellin u dat u hav not initialized any object that you have declared